# Проверочное слово

Tags: языкознание

Подобрать проверочное слово к слову остепененный

Answer (score 2):

А какую букву проверить надо?

остеп**е**нённый - степЕнный

ост**е**пенённый - стЕпень, но это исторически однокоренные слова. Степенный -имеющий степень, т.е. должность с окладом ,стоящий на значимой ступени на лестнице чинов,а значит, ведущий себя степенно-спокойно и с достоинством. Степень, ступень, ступать,стопа - исторически однокоренные.

Answer (score 0):

Если по поводу О, то русской приставки А не бывает. И на всякий случай: НН, т.к. прич. сов. вида и есть приставка.